# What are some effective methods for implementing downsampled transparency?

Tags: rendering, xbox360, playstation3, transparency

It seems that some games have managed to implement downsampled transparency, and presumably gained a significant performance boost. (Examples: Uncharted 2, Crysis 2) A while back I attempted to implement a form of this based off of [an article](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch23.html) in GPU Gems 3, but we found that it wasn't quite fast enough to be a win for us.

I'm looking for information on other techniques of implementing downsampled transparency, especially targeting the PS3 and Xbox360.

Comment: I don't know if you are going to find anything else as good as the article you posted. Maybe you somehow messed up in your implementation?

Comment: It could be that there are better ways of doing that implementation. It did help us out in the worst case, but hurt us in the average case, and ultimately wasn't a big enough win to justify putting it it.

I have heard of hardware specific tricks that require only one pass, taking advantage of MSAA to render downsampled translucency while using a full res depth buffer. But I haven't found any info about that online, it may be NDA information.

Answer (score 3):

I found a good [GDC presentation](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014348/HALO-REACH-Effects) on how they did it in Halo Reach.

EDIT: Found another method, for upsampling in 1 pass without redrawing the effects. It uses [Bilateral Upsampling](http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/ShopfMixedResolutionRendering.pdf), but that one upsampling pass is apparently very expensive.

And yet another method: [Nearest-Depth Upsampling](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/sdk/11/OpacityMappingSDKWhitePaper.pdf). This one looks more promising, faster than Bilateral Upsampling, and it claims it was actually used in Batman: Arkham Asylum.